# ZF1 Remove 'public/' from url

Tags: zend-framework

Using Zend_Navigation, i noticed that it's add '/public/' to all links.

How to remove this addition form url?

```
$navigation = array(
    array(
        'label'      => 'Home',
        'title'      => 'Go Home',
        'module'     => 'default',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action'     => 'index',
        'route'      => 'default',
        'order'      => -100 // make sure home is the first page
    ),
    array(
        'label'      => 'Test static page!',
        'route'      => 'pages',
        'params'     => array(
            'permalink'     => 'test'
        )
    )
);
            $nav = new Zend_Navigation($navigation);
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple. Edit your bootsrap.ini like this:

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/"
```

Comment: great, didn't need .htaccess afterall, !

Comment: check out [this](http://developerspark.net/2013/01/zend-framework-how-to-remove-public-folder-from-url/) and [this](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-framework-on-a-shared-host/) for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way I'm using:

Put `index.php` to the root directory.

Define `APPLICATION_PATH` as following:

```
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/application'));
```

Run project without `public` part.

Answer (score 0):

in your `.htaccess` file you need to add a rule for that,

try following,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

add these line in your .htaccess line, and see if it works..

or you can create a virtual host, which directly points to your public directory,
as folllowing,

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/project/public"
    ServerName localhost.test
    ServerAlias localhost.test
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/project/public">   
        DirectoryIndex index.php      
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

you need to follow somethings first in order to create a vhost.

[OFFICIAL DOC FOR VIRTUAL HOST](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html)

Comment: htaccess doesnt help(